# Group by value of sum of columns with Pandas

Tags: python, group-by, pandas, dataframe

I got lost in Pandas doc and features trying to figure out a way to  `groupby` a `DataFrame` by the values of the sum of the columns.

for instance, let say I have the following data :

```
In [2]: dat = {'a':[1,0,0], 'b':[0,1,0], 'c':[1,0,0], 'd':[2,3,4]}

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(dat)

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
   a  b  c  d
0  1  0  1  2
1  0  1  0  3
2  0  0  0  4
```

I would like columns `a`, `b` and `c` to be grouped since they all have their sum equal to 1. The resulting DataFrame would have columns labels equals to the sum of the columns it summed. Like this :

```
   1  9
0  2  2
1  1  3
2  0  4
```

Any idea to put me in the good direction ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Was there a section of the docs that you found particularly confusing? Or was it just tough to translate what the docs were saying to your particular problem? If you have any improvement be sure to share them on [Github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues)

Comment: [Done](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6288). Thanks again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you go:

```
In [57]: df.groupby(df.sum(), axis=1).sum()
Out[57]: 
   1  9
0  2  2
1  1  3
2  0  4

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

`df.sum()` is your grouper. It sums over the 0 axis (the index), giving you the two groups: `1` (columns `a`, `b`, and, `c`) and `9` (column `d`) . You want to group the columns (`axis=1`), and take the sum of each group.

Answer (score 0):

Because `pandas` is designed with database concepts in mind, it's really expected information to be stored together in rows, not in columns. Because of this, it's usually more elegant to do things row-wise. Here's how to solve your problem row-wise:

```
dat = {'a':[1,0,0], 'b':[0,1,0], 'c':[1,0,0], 'd':[2,3,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dat)

df = df.transpose()
df['totals'] = df.sum(1)

print df.groupby('totals').sum().transpose()
#totals  1  9
#0       2  2
#1       1  3
#2       0  4
```

Comment: Oh! I think @TomAugspurger's answer is better than mine! (We must have typed them at the same time!)

Comment: I started out the same way as yours before remembering the `axis` argument to groupby. I don't think I'd ever used it before.